# How to give different css file based on device width in Nativescript Angular Mobile App

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying with `NativeScript-Platform-CSS`, `NativeScript FontScale pluggins` but those are not supporting.

Is there any way to be done with `nativescript angular`?

Comment: use media query

Comment: Try using [nativescript-platform-css](https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-platform-css). The plugin is paid now, an easier workaround is to write a directive and put it on the layout you like, the directive shall add the class name based on device size.

Comment: i want to apply different css file like app1080.css, Which condition should i add to directive

Answer (score 0):

## This can be done as:-

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){

@import url('assets/css/myStyle.css');

}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

@import url('assets/css/myStyle2.css');

}
```

Comment: thank you, its not working i have tried already, is it working in your App?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-built css to style based on different device type (i.e phone, tablet) with different screen sizes.

For tablets

```
.ns-tablet.button-style {
  width: 90%;
}
```

For phones you can specify

```
.ns-phone.button-style {
  width: 90%;
}
```

To know more, refer to this link: [NativeScript UI and Styling](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#root-views-css-classes)